# Support Token Based Authentication in Swagger Documentation for Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying out swagger([SwashBuckle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/swashbuckle)) for generating web api documentation. I have successfully generated the documentation using [Web API documentation using swagger](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/) but I am not able to successfully send API requests, as we have token based authentication (custom header for authentication purpose) for few of the methods.

I tried to find out sample code/resources for the same but did not have much luck. Please let me know if someone has implemented/came across similar thing in their application.

Comment: You really should add to the question what steps you actually took in the code when trying to add it, and what were the result especially if those were partial. It is also unclear how you're testing to see if it's worked successfully or not.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem some time ago, and asked in the blog http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/ for a solution.

This was the answer that worked for me:

1.Add new file named “SwaggerExtensions”, then added new JS file named “onComplete.js”, you have to change the build action for this file to “Embedded Resource”.

2.Inside the file “onComplete.js” paste the following code:

```
$('#input_apiKey').change(function () {

var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
if (key && key.trim() != "") {
key = "Bearer " + key;
window.authorizations.add("key", new ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", key, "header"));
}
});
```

3.Open file “SwaggerConfig.cs” and inside the register method paste the code below:

```
SwaggerUiConfig.Customize(c =>
{
c.SupportHeaderParams = true;
c.InjectJavaScript(typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly, "AngularJSAuthentication.API.SwaggerExtensions.onComplete.js");
});
```

Note that you need to change the full assembly name to match your assembly name.

I believe thats it, once you run the UI you will notice that this file has been downloaded and it will set the authorization header correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any solution for the methods with OverrideAuthentication attribute specified?

Comment: I'm confused, what does AngularJS have to do with this?

Comment: @zespri It's just the Assembly where to find the "onComple.js" file. You should change it to bind your assembly name.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up API Key authorisation. The "Describing Security/Authorization Schemes" in the README at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle has details on this but in short you need to do something like the following in your call to httpConfiguration.EnableSwagger()

```
c.ApiKey("apiKey")
  .Description("API Key Authentication")
  .Name("apiKey")
  .In("header");
```

You then need to create a custom attribute derived from IDocumentFilter and apply it to the appropriate methods in your controllers. Lets say you call this ApiKeyFilter. You then need to register this with Swagger by adding the following in EnableSwagger()

```
c.OperationFilter<ApiKeyFilter>();
```

I'm not aware of sample code for an ApiKey attribute but I've used https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/SwaggerExtensions/AssignOAuth2SecurityRequirements.cs before for OAuth2, you should be able to adapt that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any solution for the methods with OverrideAuthentication attribute specified?